# Edit invoice journal entry in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

**Hello,
I need to edit the journal entry after validating an invoice does anyone has an idea how to do it?? I need to add more items**

Comment: Could you please give us an example? "I need to add more items" could be anything. Do you want to extend the invoice or maybe get a refund. Why should you want to add more items after validation?

Comment: I had added a new fields and this fields are computed in the amount so I want when I validate the invoice this fields will be added in the journal entry as credit

Answer (score 0):

You must browse to journal entry and add fields, it's very simple. If you will give us more details we can give you more details.

For example if I have in model1 field field1 which is relation to model2, I can set model2's name from model1 like this: field1.name = 'new name'

Comment: I have added a new field in the invoice form and when I validate the invoice I need that the amount of this field will be added in my journal items as a credit

Answer (score 0):

You can install the module account_cancel and have to activate cancelling for every account journal manually. When you have done it for the journal of your invoice, you can cancel the invoice and set it back to draft.

Attention: What will happen here?

1. The account move (journal entry) of that invoice will be deleted!
2. The invoice number will be stored on the invoice, so you can't delete  but edit it. After validating, the invoice number will be the same as before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to do it by a custom module not manually